# MySQL Update Trigger Prepared statment workaround?

Tags: mysql, triggers, prepared-statement

I am developing a custom Trigger for a Invoice which captures the ID on Invoice.ID for each row updated. Invoice.ID will be used to Query Orders.ID and select Orders.Quantity and Orders.SKU. I then deduct Product.Quantity for each Product.ID in Bundles (ie Bundle one consists of product1, product2 and product3)

My Update trigger is functioning properly however the issue is with the application running MySQL prepared statements which seems to Update the table multiple times with the same information (The Program is not open source, I can not alter the mysql calls). So obviously what happens is my Invoice trigger runs each time and throws off my arithmetic for deducting Product.Quantity for each product contained in a bundle product.  In the example below if the Invoice is for Box 2, the Quantity for Product 523 should be deducted by 25. Because of the Prepared mysql statements the trigger runs twice and 50 inventory is deducted instead. See the mysql.general.log below as well.

```
AFTER UPDATE ON `myDB`.`Invoice`
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE invoice_id integer;
DECLARE order_status varchar(11);
DECLARE order_sku varchar(255);
DECLARE order_quantity integer;

SET invoice_id = (SELECT InvoiceID FROM Invoice WHERE InvoiceID = NEW.InvoiceID);
SELECT Status INTO order_status FROM Invoice WHERE InvoiceID = invoice_id;
SELECT SKU INTO order_sku FROM Orders WHERE InvoiceID = invoice_id  AND SKU LIKE '%Box%';
SELECT Quantity INTO order_quantity FROM Orders WHERE InvoiceID = invoice_id AND SKU LIKE '%Box%';

IF order_status = 'Ordered' THEN
   IF order_sku = 'Box 1' THEN
       UPDATE Product
       SET Quantity = CASE ProductNo
           WHEN 525 THEN (Quantity + (-3 * order_quantity))
           WHEN 523 THEN (Quantity + (-2 * order_quantity))
           WHEN 526 THEN (Quantity + (-1 * order_quantity))
           WHEN 524 THEN (Quantity + (-1 * order_quantity))
           WHEN 502 THEN (Quantity + (-2 * order_quantity))
           WHEN 515 THEN (Quantity + (-1 * order_quantity))
           WHEN 506 THEN (Quantity + (-2 * order_quantity))
           WHEN 520 THEN (Quantity + (-1 * order_quantity))
           WHEN 514 THEN (Quantity + (-1 * order_quantity))
           WHEN 532 THEN (Quantity + (-1 * order_quantity))
           WHEN 527 THEN (Quantity + (-1 * order_quantity))
           WHEN 497 THEN (Quantity + (-1 * order_quantity))
      END
      WHERE ProductNo IN (525, 523, 526, 524, 502, 515, 506, 520, 514, 532, 527, 497);
 END IF;

 IF order_sku = 'Box 2' THEN
  UPDATE Product
    SET Quantity = Quantity + (-25 * order_quantity)
    WHERE ProductNo = 523;
 END IF;
```

Mysql.General.Log

```
 47 Prepare     [12526] UPDATE Invoice SET InvoiceNo = ?, Status = ?...
 47 Execute     [12526] UPDATE Invoice SET InvoiceNo = 208048, Status = Ordered ....
```

Is this rational thinking, because the program uses the above "prepared statement" before updating Invoice there are 2 iterations performed on the Trigger resulting in my skewed deductions on inventory?

Any insight/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for a similar solution, It was very simple and in front of me the whole time.

```
IF NEW.Status <> OLD.Status THEN
    -- DO SOMETHING IMPORTANT!
END IF;
```